# When I deploy a program when initializing the solana-test-validator what account technically deployed the contract?

Tags: validation, testing, native, solana

Is it the account that receives the genesis tokens? Or is it another address?

I'm deploying the contract like so when starting the validator:

```
solana-test-validator -r --mint E2F3fsS1HpsLb2VpEgsA5ztfo83CWFWW4jWpC6FvJ6qR --bpf-program J2bPahVXAHqLvc3TUKeJMxfhKWymh4C7mM1PZm4FfpKU ../program/target/deploy/program.so
```

Comment: not sure if testnet explorer would indicate https://explorer.solana.com/?cluster=testnet

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's the one in your config.

You may check the config with

```
solana config get
```

Look for the keypair path and use:

```
solana address --keypair <path to keypair in config>
```

Or easiest is

```
solana address
```

It's almost always the one in your config

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually "no account"! The program accounts through `--bpf-program` are part of the genesis accounts on the chain, so there's no actual deployment performed.